# Vim autocmd works on FocusGained but not BufWritePost

Tags: vim

I've got this in my `.vimrc`

```
au FocusGained * echo "hello world"
```

And it works — when I switch to my vim window, I see "hello world" in the status bar. But if I switch this to:

```
au BufWritePost * echo "hello world"
```

And then save a file with `:w`, the "hello world" is not displayed. Why not?

Comment: I don't understand what require does from that page you linked. Perhaps [BufWriteCmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWriteCmd) could work?

Comment: What happens if you replace it by `au BufWritePost * echo "hello world"`? Could you add the definition of the `:Require` command? BTW, the colon is not required for autocommands.

Comment: @yolenoyer i updated to echo command, and I see the same issue.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Thanks! I tried BufWriteCmd, and it works, but now I also need to include a "w" since it seems to replace the default functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Per @jeremysprofile's comment, this can work if I switch to `BufWriteCmd`:

```
au BufWriteCmd * w | echo "hello world"
```

Notice that I have to prefix with `w |` to run the default behavior of the "write" command before running the command I need. In my case, I wanted to run a `vim-fireplace` `Require` command, so it also helped to use the `silent!` prefix:

```
au BufWriteCmd *.clj w | silent! Require
```